# Interrupt not interrupting the thread, forced to stop

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, interrupt, interrupt-handling

Requirement: I'll first state my requirement and how I came over it. I was supposed to make 3 calls to back end-systems, but couldn't afford sequential calls, as they would take too long and breach the SLA.

Solution: I used the ExecutorService to create 3 threads and gave them each 3 different tasks.

```
final ExecutorService service = Executors
                .newFixedThreadPool(NUMBEROFTHREADSTOSPAWNSIZE);
                getSubsFutureCall = service
                        .submit(new GetSubsCallable(request));
                getAccountDetailCall = service
                        .submit(new GetAccountInfoCallable(request));
                getProvisioningCall = service
                        .submit(new GetProvisioningFromCallable(request));
                responseGetSubs = getSubsFutureCall
                        .get(TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISECONDS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                responseGetAccountDetail = getAccountDetailCall
                        .get(TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISECONDS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                responseFromCPF = (SubscriptionType) getProvisioningCPFCall
                        .get(TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISECONDS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Resultant problem: Even after the timeout, the spawned threads continue to run, which is undesirable. Hence, I introduced a monitoring thread, which fetches the list of running threads and interrupts them.

```
for (Thread t : timeoutList) {      
   t.interrupt();
}
```

**This interrupt is not working!!!**

I remember doing similar thing in another project, it worked so beautifully. Our OS was OSX(Apple Mac). Now, I am working on Windows OS. Could that be the problem?

In desperation I added:

```
for (Thread t : timeoutList) {
   t.interrupt();
   if(!t.isInterrupted() || t.isAlive()){
      t.stop();
   }
}
```

Can somebody tell what can I do to avoid calling t.stop() method and why the t.interrupt call is not working?

Answer (score 0):

As per this documentation : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt(), if the thread is not blocked and you call interrupt on it, nothing happens, except a status flag 'interrupt' is set.

So you have to handle interrupting on the thread's side :

```
for (int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    heavyCrunch(inputs[i]);
    if (Thread.interrupted()) {
        // We've been interrupted: no more crunching.
        return;
    }
}
```

You may find more examples here :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Andrei. I know after a bit of Googling that isInterrupted check should be done for looping jobs, like the one your example. But, I am doing a webservice call which might take a while, in each task and some transformation after that. 

Is there no way to interrupt that? Because, what I fear is, if the web-service, never responds. Won't that block that particular thread, possibly, forever, until the next server restart?

Comment: @AnoopHallimala, I am afraid that you have to time out the remote connection in the thread itself. Thread.stop() is deprecated and you shouldn't use it. You can find more details there : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html